# Soma quantidades em objetos com propriedades idênticas

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou fazendo um trabalho e me deparei com uma questão que aparentemente é bem simples, mas não estou conseguindo. Eu preciso fazer um `reduce` (ou poderia ser de outra forma também) para **somar a quantidade dos itens com a propriedade idêntica**. Por exemplo:

```js
let arr = [
  {id: "xxx", amount: 2}, 
  {id: "xxx", amount: 7}, 
  {id: "yyy", amount: 2},
  {id: "yyy", amount: 5},
  {id: "zzz", amount: 5}
];
```

Para esse `Array` acima, eu precisaria obter o seguinte resultado:

```js
[
  {id: "xxx", amount: 9},
  {id: "yyy", amount: 7},
  {id: "zzz", amount: 5}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisa mesmo usar `reduce`? Um *loop* simples resolve:

```js
let arr = [
  {id: "xxx", amount: 2}, 
  {id: "xxx", amount: 7}, 
  {id: "yyy", amount: 2},
  {id: "yyy", amount: 5},
  {id: "zzz", amount: 5}
];

let result = {};
for (const e of arr) {
    if (result[e.id]) { // id já existe, somar amount
        result[e.id].amount += e.amount;
    } else { // id não existe, criar o objeto com o amount inicial
        result[e.id] = { id: e.id, amount: e.amount };
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

A ideia é criar um objeto cujas chaves são os `id`'s, e os valores são os objetos que terão os `amount`'s acumulados.

Se o `id` ainda não existe neste objeto, eu coloco o `amount` inicial. Se o `id` já existe, basta somar ao `amount` já existente.

Depois, basta pegar o `values` deste objeto, que o resultado será um array contendo os objetos que tem os valores acumulados.

---

Mas claro, também dá para fazer com `reduce`:

```js
let arr = [
  {id: "xxx", amount: 2}, 
  {id: "xxx", amount: 7}, 
  {id: "yyy", amount: 2},
  {id: "yyy", amount: 5},
  {id: "zzz", amount: 5}
];

let result = arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    if (acc[val.id]) {
        acc[val.id].amount += val.amount;
    } else {
        acc[val.id] = { id: val.id, amount: val.amount };
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

A ideia é a mesma do código anterior, mas todo o trabalho é feito na função de *callback*.

Comment: Ajudou muito. Os dois códigos são brilhantes.